# How to set text on right site in radio button list

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

i have following code in cs file

```
QueMAnsM[] Answers = Curr.AnsM;

                        rdbAns.DataSource = Answers;
                        rdbAns.DataTextField = "Answer";
                        rdbAns.DataValueField = "AnsId";
                        rdbAns.DataBind();                        
                        rdbAns.TextAlign = TextAlign.Right;
```

where rdbAns is asp:radiobuttonlist control

i have set TextAlign property to right (This code is at page load)
but text is still showing at left side 
what is wrong with this code

Comment: Does it makea difference when you set the property _before_ you databind the rbl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `TextAlign` property to "Right" on the list .

```
<asp:RadioButtonList id="RadioButtonList1"
     RepeatDirection="Vertical" 
     RepeatLayout="Table"  
     TextAlign="Right"  
     runat="server">
```

OR, In code behind :

```
RadioButtonList1.TextAlign = TextAlign.Right;
```

OR, Perhaps you can use some css. 
Give your list a `CssClass="rbListWrap"` and add following style:

```
.rbListWrap {
            width: 500px;
         }

         .rbListWrap tr td {
           height:20px;
            vertical-align: middle;  
            padding: 5px;
            width: 33%;
         }

         .rbListWrap input { 
            float:right;
         }

         .rbListWrap label { 
            position: relative;
            padding-left:20px;
         }
```

Comment: allready set TextAligh="Right" in aspx, but still not working...is this problem due to data bindiang...

Comment: OKzz..use some css..Worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Set **CheckAlign** Property to **MiddleLeft** if you want to move the text of the radio button to the  left. You can move it to other positions if you want to.

[image]